# Is there anything wrong with this use of the axiom of choice?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have a proof of the following theorem:

*Let A be a finite set and X be a perfectly normal topological space, and let $\{(A,\succsim_x): x\in X\}$ be a family of binary relations on $A$ satisfying certain conditions. Then there exists $g: A\times X \rightarrow \mathbb R $ such that $g(a,\cdot)$ is continuous for all $a$ in $A$ and for each $x$ in $X$, $a\succsim_x b$ if and only if $g(a,x) \geq g(b,x)$.*

Aside: The proof proceeds by standard induction and uses finiteness of $A$ to obtain lower semi-continuity of the lower envelope of lower semi-continuous functions together with Michael's selection theorem for continuity of $g(a,\cdot)$.

I then claim that, by the axiom of choice, I can extend to the case of countable $A$ by the following argument:

First I well order $A$ and then let $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be the collection of initial segments of $A$ (that is $\lvert A_n\rvert=n-1$ for each $n$ and $n\leq m$ implies $A_n \subseteq A_m$). Then $\lim_n A_n =A$ and the above theorem holds on each $A_n$, and by finite induction I can find a sequence of functions $f_n: A_n\times X\rightarrow \mathbb R$, each with the same properties as the $g$ above, and moreover such that $n\leq m$ implies $f_n(a,\cdot)=f_m(a,\cdot)$ for all $a$ in $A_n$.

Let $a_n$ be the maximal element of $A_n$ for each $n\geq 2$. By the axiom of (countable) choice, I can choose $h:A\times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that for each $n$, $h(a_n,\cdot):= f_n(a_n,\cdot)$, and moreover, the above theorem now holds for $h$, that is $h(a,\cdot)$ is continuous for each $a$ and $h(\cdot,x)$ order preserving for each $x$.

My question is:

*Is there anything wrong with this use of the axiom of choice?*

Comment: There is a $g$ appearing out of nowhere somewhere in your question.

Comment: Side note: what is the maximal element of $A_1=\emptyset$? Also, out of curiosity, what are the "certain conditions" you refer to in the first paragraph?

Comment: The conditions are that each relation is transitive and total, and the sets $\{x:a\succ_x b\}$ are open.

Comment: This title **really** have to be replaced by something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can choose the functions $f_n$ so that they are compatible, then the argument is legitimate. If you can actually *define* them so that they are compatible, rather than merely show that they exist, you don’t need any choice; otherwise, you probably need the axiom of dependent choice. The hypothesis that $A$ is countably infinite already ensures that it has an enumeration $A=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, ordinary recursion (possibly using dependent choice) gives you the sequence of functions $f_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, and the desired function $h$ is simply $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}f_n$. However, it is crucial that you be able to define the functions $f_n$ so that $f_n\upharpoonright A_m=f_m$ whenever $m\le n$.

Comment: If one can *define* the functions $f_n$ coherently, then indeed there is no need for the axiom of choice. But I can imagine a situation where one can prove that, for each appropriate $f_m$, there exists an appropriate extension $f_{m+1}$, without an explicit definition and without a definable way to choose among the (possibly many) available $f_m$'s.  In such a situation, it seems the axiom of dependent choice would be needed.

Comment: @Andreas: Good point; I was sloppy. Better now?

Comment: Yes, definitely better.

Comment: @AndreasBlass just to make sure I understand: by *define* you do not mean *construct*, correct? So in the above, other than the initial step ($f_1=0$), because I use Michael's selection theorem, I only know that I can select an $f_{n+1}$ given that I have already selected $f_n$ at the preceding step. (Yes, I explicitly define $f_{n+1}$ to be equal to $f_n$ on the latter's domain.) In other words, if I do the *choosing* at each step, then I don't need axiom of choice. That is to say, I have what amounts to an "explicit definition" correct?

Comment: @Patrick: Does the choosing of the new value at stage $n+1$ depend on what you’ve already chosen through stage $n$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Patrick: Is the new value explicitly definable from the first $n$, or do you simply know that one exists?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for this. In my problem, Michael's selection theorem tells me there exists an extension from $A_n$ to $A_{n+1}$. I then need to choose one of them and proceed to the next step. I think I am therefore using axiom of choice at each stage, and from what you are saying, I then don't need it for the limiting case. (This issue has been raised independently by two reviewers of a paper of mine.) I should say that originally, I didn't appeal to the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Patrick: It sounds to me as if you’re using dependent choice. I can’t imagine why the reviewers care, however, unless use of choice is explicitly at issue in the paper; outside of explicitly foundational set-theoretic areas, the axiom of choice is a normal, unproblematic part of mathematics.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I agree, perhaps if explicitly write $h:=\bigcup_n f_n$ as you suggest, that will be enough to convince.

Comment: @Patrick: We can hope!